# How to securely delete versions in mac os lion

Tags: macos, versions

I know, that there is a possibility to [delete selected versions](https://apple.stackexchange.com/q/26262/9058) in Mac OS Lion.
Is there a way to *securely* delete versions?

Although I already deleted the versions by now, that I wanted to delete, but what way can I make sure, that any remains of those version is removed? (Technically: not just the inode is removed, but also it's content.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I can't think of a targeted way to do this, but this should do the trick. Delete the versions that you want to delete using the method outlined in the question you linked to. Then use Disk Utility's "Erase Free Space" option (or `diskutil secureErase freespace [level] [device]`) to write over the data.