# Did Apple get rid of autosave and versions in Mavericks?

Tags: macos, versions

<sup>(As a heads up, I've hardly used any versions of OS X newer than Snow Leopard. So, I might be missing something obvious here).</sup>

I recently installed Mountain Lion and after that Mavericks. While on Mountain Lion, I noticed the "new" versions and autosave feature (released in Lion, right?) that you could access via the context menu of a file in Finder or the arrow next to the file's app's window title.

But, now that I'm in Mavericks, I can't find it in either of these places.

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Versions is not in Finder's context menu in Mavericks and later. Apple recommends the use of the File menu to access versions of files.

> **Browse, restore, duplicate, and delete versions**
>
> 1. Open the document, then choose File > Revert To > Browse All Versions.
> 2. Click tick marks along the timeline to browse versions.
> 3. Display the version you want, then do one of the following:
>
>    - To restore your document to this version, click Restore.
>    - To duplicate this version in a new document, press the Option key and click “Restore a Copy.”
>    - To leave your document as is, without changes, click Done.

<sup>Source: [OS X Mavericks: View and restore past versions of documents](http://support.apple.com/kb/PH14378)</sup>

Documents can be reverted again using the File menu.

> **Revert a document to the last opened version**
>
> Choose File > Revert To, then choose Last Opened, Last Saved, or Previous Save.

<sup>Source: [OS X Mavericks: View and restore past versions of documents](http://support.apple.com/kb/PH14378)</sup>

Access to versions through the disclosure triangle icon next to the name of the document in the title bar is also gone—again, the File menu is preferred.

Answer (score 0):

I can't seem to find a way to play with versions via Finder, but I *am* able to use the `File >> Revert To >> ...` menu with a file open in the relevant application.

It appears that (on my machine at least) versions are integrated with Time Machine backups, so your mileage may vary.

Comment: Interesting. I have the same thing but it's only in certain apps like Preview and TextEdit. And, I don't have Time Machine setup.

Comment: Versions have never been integrated with Time Machine: *"With an interface similar to that of Time Machine, Versions shows you…"*